# Como mostrar una imagen almacenada en formato BLOB en una base de datos MySQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, blob

Tengo un campo imagen que es de tipo BLOB en mi base de datos de MySQL,los datos los recojo mediante PDO, pero a la hora de visualizarlo no me muestra nada , he buscado en internet y en todos lados me ponía lo mismo con `src="data:image/jpeg;base64`.

Este es mi código:

```
 <?php   
require_once './BaseDatos.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$bd = new BaseDatos('foro');
$imagen = $bd->SenetenciaSelect("usuarios", ["id"=>$id])[0]["image"];
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($imagen) .' "/>';
```

La variable `$imagen` retorna esto si la visualizo:

> ÿØÿà\0JFIF\0\0\0\0\0\0ÿþ\0;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 90 ÿÛ\0C\0  %# , #&\')*)-0-(0%()(ÿÛ\0C   (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((ÿÀ\0@ \0\"\0ÿÄ\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0  ÿÄ\0µ\0\0\0}\0!1AQa\"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚   %&\'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0   ÿÄ\0µ\0\0w\0!1AQaq\"2B‘¡±Á  etc.

Comment: Hola Superzuman, antes lo tenias bien, el codigo digo. Deberias reemplazar la imagen por el texto de codigo. Asi podemos copiar y pegar, la gente que no tiene buena conexion de datos (por ejemplo desde el movil) puede verlo bien sin que cargue la imagen, o puede que el enlace se rompa o el servidor se caiga y la imagen no pueda verse. Un saludo

Comment: Y si pones `var_dump($imagen)` te muestra ese código que pegaste o te dice `resource`?

Comment: He hecho una prueba local guardando una imagen en un campo blob y luego mostrándola tal y como tú propones y me ha funcionado también de manera correcta. ¿Cómo has insertado esa imagen en la base de datos? Es probable que hayas tenido algún problema relacionado con conversión de juegos de caracteres o quizá sea un problema similar. ¿Sueles usar `SET NAMES utf8` o `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todo apunta a que es un problema de conversión de juegos de caracteres que está corrompiendo los datos de tu `BLOB` o bien estás sufriendo algún problema relacionado con usar las funciones obsoletas a partir de PHP 5.5 de [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/intro.mysql) o mal escapado del SQL.

---

**Problemas relacionados con el juego de caracteres:**

Si en algún momento usas `SET CHARACTER SET utf8` tras establecer la conexión el cliente empezará a realizar conversión de caracteres incluso en los campos de tipo `BLOB` desde el juego de caracteres en el que esté la tabla.

Si usas en su lugar `SET NAMES utf8`, tanto el servidor como el cliente acordarán el mismo juego de caracteres para todo y no habrá conversión en el lado del cliente que pueda corromper los datos.

[Mira los datos de esta página](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html).

En ella puedes ver que [`SET NAMES 'charset_name'`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-names.html) es equivalente a:

```
SET character_set_client = charset_name;
SET character_set_results = charset_name;
SET character_set_connection = charset_name;
```

Sin embargo [`SET CHARACTER SET 'charset_name'`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-character-set.html) equivale a:

```
SET character_set_client = charset_name;
SET character_set_results = charset_name;
SET collation_connection = @@collation_database;
```

Por lo que si la tabla está en su valor por defecto ([`latin1_swedish_ci`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_database)) se estarán corrompiendo los datos.

---

**Problemas relacionados con el mal escapado de SQL:**

Para insertar los datos de manera adecuada en la base de datos debes modificar tu código y usar [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string) en lugar de [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/addslashes):

```
$fp = fopen($ruta, 'r');
$datos_image = fread($fp, filesize($ruta));
$datos_image = mysql_real_escape_string($datos_image);
fclose($fp);
```

De esa manera no tendrás problemas con caracteres extraños. Deberías probar también a usar [`mysql_set_charset()`](http://php.net/mysql-set-charset).

Aún así, **te insto a migrar tu código a [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) o, mejor aún, a [PDO](http://php.net/pdo-mysql)**. De esa manera podrás hacer consultas preparadas con asignación de campos en las que no tendrás problemas con el escapado de cadenas.

Answer (score 3):

A mi me resulto esto

```
echo '<img height="80" width="80" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($fila["ImagenCateg"]).'"/>';
```

Answer (score 2):

## EDIT : Ejemplo completo

```
<?php
    /*
     *Modifica modo de conexión, este ejemplo usa mysqli, pero puedes cambiarlo a PDO
     *Modifica las credenciales de conexión: usuario, password, nombre de la BD
     *Modifica los nombres de tablas y columnas
    */
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("phppot_examples");
    $sql = "SELECT imageId FROM output_images ORDER BY imageId DESC"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>List BLOB Images</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
//En $row["imageId"] debes cambiar imageId por como se llama en tu tabla la columna que tiene la id de la imagen
<img src="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $row["imageId"]; ?>" /><br/>
<?php       
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

---

Tres posibles soluciones (@deprecated):

**A.**
Usando tu variable `$imagen` después de `$imagen=$bd...` pones esto y comentas el actual código en el que intentas mostrar la imagen:

```
<img src="image.php?id=<?php echo $imagen; ?>" />
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $imagen;
```

**B.**
También usando tu variable `$imagen` después de `$imagen=$bd...` comenta tu actual código para mostrar la imagen y copia y pega esto:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($imagen).'"/>';
```

**C.**
¿No funciona? Asegúrate de que tu imagen es correcta en la base de datos.

Comment: He probado y nada, asi es como leeo la imagen de un input type="file" $ruta = $_FILES['txt_image']['tmp_name'];
                $fp = fopen($ruta, 'r');
                $datos_image = fread($fp, filesize($ruta));
                $datos_image = addslashes($datos_image);
                fclose($fp); $datos_image es lo que inserto, la base de datos la gestiono mediante PDO

Comment: He editado la respuesta poniendo un ejemplo completo. Debes adaptar el código a tus credenciales de conexión, nombre de BD, tabla, columnas.

Comment: No me funciono, sigue sin verse.

Comment: @superzuman ¿Puedes comentar el error que da? Encontrarás el error en el error log

Comment: A mí me funciono la opción B, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Guiándome por tu comentario en la respuesta de @a-cedano.
Me armé una prueba y parece que el problema está en que antes de guardar el BLOB le aplicas addslashes pero no le aplicas el stripslashes al recuperar la info

este es mi codigo de prueba, (asume un archivo prueba.jpg válido en la misma ruta)

```
<?php

$ruta = 'prueba.jpg';
$fp = fopen($ruta, 'r');
$datos_image = fread($fp, filesize($ruta));
$datos_image = addslashes($datos_image);
fclose($fp);

echo '<img
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(stripslashes($datos_image)) .' "/>';
//var_dump($datos_image);

?>
```