# Problema para mostrar imagen en tabla junto a otros datos.-

Tags: php

Nuevamente necesito si me pueden orientar, no puedo visualizar la imagen en una tabla junto a otros datos, todo me funciona a excepción de la imagen.-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM platos";
$resultado=$conn->query($sql);
while($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $filas['nomplato'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $filas['ingredientes'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $filas['costo'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align=center><img src=".$filas['imagen']."/></td>"; // aca el problema
echo "<td><a href=editar.php?id={$filas['Idplatos']}>Editar</a></td>
<td><a href=eliminar.php?id={$filas['Idplatos']}>Eliminar</a></td> ";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<a href=Adminplatos.html class='boton'>Nuevo auto</a>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: print de info]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La etiqueta src tiene que ir entre comillas por lo que te faltaría añadirlas: <img src='".$filas['imagen']."' />. Por otro lado porque no se te ven los demás datos?

Comment: Los demás datos se ven, imagina que todos esos caracteres que muestra por la imagen, hace que los demás datos queden al final, pero están...gracias

Comment: Muy bien, a ver si eso te ayuda.

Comment: No me sirvió, sigue mostrándome los caracteres...se agradece igual

Comment: Haz un echo "<script>alert('".$filas['imagen']."')</script>" o un echo "<script>console.log('".$filas['imagen']."')</script>" para ver que es lo que te trae de la base de datos.

Comment: ningún mensaje..

Comment: Pues eso es que no te trae nada de la base de datos. Podrías poner como es la tabla platos de tu base de datos?

Comment: agregue la info de la tabla, ahora si bajo el blob y lo abro con el paint me muestra la imagen.-

Comment: No sabía que era del tipo Blob, aquí tienes varias soluciones: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50468/como-mostrar-una-imagen-almacenada-en-formato-blob-en-una-base-de-datos-mysql-en

Comment: mira aun no me muestra la imagen, pero al menos ahora no me salen todos esos caracteres, pero me figura 'Notice: Undefined variable: imagen in ..\fastfood\listado.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined variable: imagen in ..\fastfood\listado.php on line 45'

Comment: No veo ninguna variable con ese nombre en el archivo php que has puesto.

Comment: Bueno ahora la linea de código esta asi 'echo "<td align=center><img src=tipoimg:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode('imagen').' width=\"130px\" height=\"130px\" /></td>";' con eso consegui que desapareciera el error de variable Undefined, pero aun no se me ve la imagen, la tabla la hice de nuevo con el chartset utf8 unicode, asi que ya se me agota el tiempo...

Comment: No deberías pasarle la variable $filas['imagen'] en vez de ese 'imagen'? Creo que no sabe lo que es ese 'imagen'.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)  eso pasa...

Comment: echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(stripslashes($filas['imagen'])) .' "/>';

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'data' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'  pero...para el stripslashes, no debia guardar  addslashes?

Comment: src=tipoimg:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($filas['imagen'])." de esa linea me lanza parse error...en cambio si dejo solo esta parte <img src=".base64_encode($filas['imagen'])."/> me muestra el icono pero no la imagen, a esta altura ya elimine la base y la cree de nuevo y me sale lo mismo...ya no se que hacer, el resto de los datos están incluso si bajo el archivo director de la base como archivo .bin y lo abro con el Paint me muestra el archivo...

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM platos";
$resultado=$conn->query($sql);
while($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $filas['nomplato'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $filas['ingredientes'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $filas['costo'] . "</td>";
echo '<td align=center><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($filas['imagen']). '"/></td>'; // aca el problema
echo "<td><a href=editar.php?id={$filas['Idplatos']}>Editar</a></td>
<td><a href=eliminar.php?id={$filas['Idplatos']}>Eliminar</a></td> ";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<a href=Adminplatos.html class='boton'>Nuevo auto</a>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bryro gracias, pero src=tipoimg:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($filas['imagen'])." de esa linea me lanza parse error...en cambio si dejo solo esta parte <img src=".base64_encode($filas['imagen'])."/> me muestra el icono pero no la imagen, a esta altura ya elimine la base y la cree de nuevo y me sale lo mismo...ya no se que hacer, el resto de los datos están incluso si bajo el archivo director de la base como archivo .bin y lo abro con el Paint me muestra el archivo... – SoloEddo hace 2 horas

Comment: como estas guardando la imagen en la base de datos? que formato tiene???

Comment: la imagen en longblob

Comment: cual es el error que te envia y el formato de la imagen es??

Comment: ya no muestra error, no muestra la imagen...

Comment: Ve a developers mode y mira que sale en esa linea

Comment: perdon...donde?